# Average of all entries of a matrix function norm

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

Lets say you have a function which takes the average of a matrix entries. Is it a norm?

I begun with declaring a simple matrix:

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We know that this matrix is not a norm because $||A|| = 0$ even though $A \ne 0$. And the function which takes the average of this matrix will give $0$, but I'm not quite sure what this means, how to proceed or if I am even on the right track.

Comment: You are done. A norm should satisfy that property and that function doesn't. You could check some of the other properties, for fun or to see if it is at least a [semi-norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Seminorm.html). Is it always non-negative?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, then the average of its entries is $-\frac14$, whereas a norm never takes values smaller than $0$.

Comment: But wouldn't the norm be $|-1/4| = 1/4$?

Comment: @osk You wrote that your function is the average of the matrix entries and the average of the entries of my matrix is $-\frac14$.

Comment: @osk The average of the absolute value of the entries is indeed a norm (it is a kind of rescaled $1$-Frobenius norm)

Comment: @Surb That can't be what the osk has in mind. Otherwise, he would not have stated that $\left\|\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right\|=0$.

Comment: No you are right @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: So can we conclude that for a function that does something on a matrix $A$ is only a norm if the function output is always greater than $0$?

Comment: I know that this is not what is stated in the OP. However, while $f(M)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n M_{i,j}$ is not a norm, the function $g(M)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n |M_{i,j}|$ is a norm on $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$.

Comment: @osk .... do you know the definition of a norm?

Comment: @osk If it is a norm, then the output mus always be greater than or equal to $0$. Of course, even if that occurs, you can't automatically conclude that it is a norm.

Comment: @Surb im slightly confused because I do understand vector and matrix norms and which properties they have, but this is for a function (which in this case returns a single value)

Comment: @osk Are you aware of some norm that outputs several values?

Comment: @osk $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ is a vector space, $\Bbb R^n$ is a vector space too. The definition of norm is given for a general vector space $V$ and the required properties are always the same "regardless" of $V$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos True, there isn't any

Comment: @osk you should take the time to read the [definition of norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the help both of you, I just solved a similar problem correctly and think I understand it now. Going to read up on it a bit more to make sure.